# Reading file to imageView

Tags: file, javafx, imageview

I'm tryin to pick a file and read it into an imageView. I'm using java fx.

Here's my code:

> ```
>    public void changeImage() {
>
>     try {
>
>         FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
>         fileChooser.setTitle("Choose Image");
>
>         fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
>                 new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"),
>                 new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"));
>         File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(ScreenController.stage);
>
>         if (selectedFile != null) {
>             File file = selectedFile;
>             File desc = new File("/" + file.getName());
>             FileUtils.copyFile(file, desc);
>             Image img = new Image(desc.getPath());
>             profileImage.setImage(img);
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         System.err.println(e);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

The problem seems to be Image img = new Image (desc.getPath()); getting an error that the file does not exist. But it does and it is a image.
// Alex

Comment: What is FileUtils? Does it copy the file synchronously or asynchronously? Also, don't use Swing's JFileChooser with JavaFX; use `javafx.stage.FileChooser`.

Comment: It copys the file. Then i'm readying the new file into the imageView. Okay thanks i'll look into it.

Comment: Right! got JavaFX filechooser now but my problem is still there. How do i display the image that i'm coosing (as a file) in the imageView?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Also, are you sure the file really exists when you are creating the Image? Add in `System.out.println("File exists? "+desc.exists());` after the call to `copyFile`

Comment: File exists? true
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Image` constructor needs a String representation of a URL, not a filesystem path.

Replace

```
Image img = new Image(desc.getPath());
```

with

```
Image img = new Image(desc.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```